# Invalid or unexpected token running jQuery to console

Tags: jquery

I try to do this with jQuery:

I have an id with a specific class. When scrolling this class changes to another class. So, i need to check if this id has the specific class then to add class to another id.

This is what i tried directly through Console of Chrome but i get Uncaught `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

```
if (jQuery(#header).hasClass("affix") ) {
  jQuery(#logo).addClass("otherlogo");
}
```

Comment: That's actually wrong code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an invalid syntax. You need to add quotes around the selectors, as they are strings. Change it this way:

```
if (jQuery("#header").hasClass("affix")) {
  jQuery("#logo").addClass("otherlogo");
}
```

The `#header` and `#logo` should be strings.

Comment: You are awesome! Now its working but i have another problem. Possibly there is a javascript/jQuery that while scrolling adds the class to header id. So if i run the above code and then scroll down and header takes the affix class, then my code does not work. If, after i have scrolled and header has class affix, then my code workds. Can i somehow make it work and before scrolling and after?

Comment: Check page here: http://eurekaescape.gr/index.php. You will see the section with header id and below the p with logo id. While scrolling you can see class of header change.

Comment: Any ideas on this?Can you see this through the link to the above comment?

Comment: @PantelisB I was unable to see it yesterday. Today it is accessible. Lemme check and get back to you.

Comment: @PantelisB It works for me. So what exactly is the problem nnow?

Comment: Ok, scroll up to the start of page then open Console run the if code and then scroll down. This does not work for me, when while scrolling down class of header changes. Now, scroll down a bit, reload the page and then run code from console again. Now code runs. So my problem is that this code does not run during navigation of page

Comment: In simplest words, this script does not load dynamically each time that header's class changes, only if it has this class. So, page loads and if header has this class then i get my result but if not, and header takes class after with javascript, this condition fails. So i need something to track change of header class

Comment: @PantelisB Ah okay... Lemme have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes:

```
if (jQuery("#header").hasClass("affix") ) {
  jQuery("#logo").addClass("otherlogo");
}
```

Comment: What about his missing quotes?   Oh... *you're*   :P